# Accommodating page numbers with narrow margins

Tags: margins, pdftex

**Problem:** I'm having trouble getting page numbers to display in a LaTeX document.

**Background:** I have a document with 0.3in margins that I suspect covers up the page numbers. A very similar document with 0.5in margins displays the page numbers. The preambles are identical except for the 0.2in difference. If it makes any difference, the document is built in R using the Sweave package. This is my most recent attempt:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{setspace, relsize}
\usepackage{moreverb}        
\usepackage[pdftex]{lscape}    
\usepackage{longtable}         
\usepackage{url}               
\usepackage[margin=.3in, landscape]{geometry} 
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{pdfpages}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}

% New command to make R code stand out
\newcommand{\co}[1]{\texttt{\smaller #1}}

\title{MIND-USA Site Report}
\author{Screening, Exclusions and Enrollment}
\date{\today}
\pagestyle{fancy}
\rfoot{\thepage}
\begin{document}
\SweaveOpts{concordance=TRUE}

\maketitle
```

**What I've tried:**

```
\pagestyle{plain}
```

This didn't do anything for the numbering, but the document compiled.

```
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\pagestyle{fancy}
\rfoot{\thepage}
```

This also didn't do anything, but compiled.

I hope that provides the right amount of information and is an appropriate/helpful question!

Comment: Try adding `includeheadfoot` as part of the options to [`geometry`](http://ctan.org/pkg/geometry), otherwise the margins are only for the text block body.

Comment: Does the addition of `includeheadfoot` provide you with an answer? Of course, it affects the entire text block dimension.

Comment: Yes! That worked. I did what you suggested and changed the \pagestyle{fancy} to \pagestyle{plain}. Thanks.

Comment: It actually looks good. No duplicates or missing numbers!